# How to handle autoresizing on UIButton elements which has been created dynamically

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uibutton, autoresizingmask

I create some buttons dynamically on my view and i decide their frames according to some of my JSON respone parameters. But i want to autoresize them when the device(dsimulator) rotates. I can easily do this on interface builder but can't do anything on dynamic ones. Can someone help?
**EDIT**

Here is a snipped of my code

```
if (button.tag==1) {
    button.frame = CGRectMake(30.0f, yPosition, 200.0f, buttonHeight);
}
if (button.tag==2) {
    button.frame = CGRectMake(280.0f, yPosition, 200.0f, buttonHeight);
}
if (button.tag==3) {
    button.frame = CGRectMake(530.0f, yPosition, 200.0f, buttonHeight);
}
```

There is no problem when using Portraid mode but when it rotates to Landscape a big empty area stays on the right side of the screen. How can i fix this?(I mean, when i rotate, i want the buttons got to the center of the scren's width)

**EDIT:**
I played with autoresizing on Size Inspector(Xcode 4.3) with my xib file and it works great, but whatever i did i couldn't resize the dynamically created buttons after rotation. I tried almost all of [AutoresizingMask enums of UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) but nothing changes. Can someone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes you've set up in your interface builder file are the `UIViewAutoresizing` attributes.

Take a look at [this documentation from Apple on the UIView class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816) (which your button is a subclass of); look for the `UIViewAutoresizing` attribute. That's the one you'll want.

**Update:** Here's a snippet of code for an MKMapView that uses this ability:

```
mainMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 239, 280, 122)];
[mainMapView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
```

With `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`, the map view moves down when the user answers the phone --- it fixes the map's position relative to the top of the screen.

Dig around in the documentation and you'll find the autoresizing mask that works best for your situation.

Comment: i have decided the frames statically(frame=...) so whatever i use it doesn't change anything. Can you please give some code example?

Comment: Have you tried combinations of the AutoResizingMask? You should be able to programmatically do anything you're able to do in IB.

Answer (score 2):

You can define by code what was the expected behavior when the device is rotated.

You can take a look at: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

and

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAutoresizing

You need to set the button behavior when you add it like:

```
[button setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
```

Comment: I didn't get what exactly you want, but you tried the mask I put there? If you want more complex operations you can do what is in apples doc in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html and override the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

Comment: I want to resize the frame of buttons. And i create these buttons dynamically

Comment: Ok, but the autoresizingMask is supposed to work in your code, can you give more information? Your problem is supposed to be solved using UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin, You have an view that encapsulate the buttons?

Comment: I'm not sure about encapsulation, i tried [button setAutoResazingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin]; but it didnt work